# How many ways are there to get from one point to another on a (simple) chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

[image]

A king is placed on the chessboard starting where the blue circle is (1,1).
He can move to the **right, up or diagonally**.

The ending point is marked yellow(8,8).

How many ways are there for the king to get from (1,1) to (8,8) **if (3,4) has to be included in the path?**

I understand what happens when I'm limited to moving up and right, but I don't know where to start here

Comment: So, what happens when you move up or right only?

Comment: You have to exclude loops somehow, otherwise the answer is clearly $+\infty$.

Comment: The answer is 17025. Perhaps I forgot to mention I can only move one step at a time. I also meant that I can find the number of combinations of up/right movements to get from point A to point B. My english is awful when it comes to math, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your "diagonally" refers to "diagonal up-right", it's fairly easy to make the route options calculation in Excel:

[image]

Equally you could do this as two separate problems, one to cross a $3\times 4$ space ($25$ options) and one to cross a $5\times 6$ space ($681$ options) and then multiply.

---

Taking this as two route-option problems "glued together", you can see patterns reminiscent of Pascal's Triangle in the bottom left of the diagram.

These are the [Delannoy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number) forming the Delannoy array or "tribonacci triangle". Essentially you will always have some summation to do to calculate them.

Comment: Now  I see the  $17\,025$.  (+1)

Comment: Any idea on how I could calculate this mathematically on a piece of paper using binomials/factorials/similar?I'm expecting similar problems on an exam soon, can't really use anything else... although I do understand the principle excel is using

Comment: Updated with a link to some more information, found through [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001850).